# Minecraft 1.8.1. MAC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Can you download more than 1 mod on one specific world? I have searched this question up but I was unsuccessfull. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have more than one mod active in a game, however not all mods work well together. I suggest you do more research as this is done very frequently and it is rather easy to learn the specifics.

Comment: Research on the mods?

Comment: Any mod worth it's salt has a forum topic or its own website that gives information how to install it. Beyond that it usually turns into trial and error to learn which mods work together and which don't. Also many mods use Mod APIs such as FORGE which is designed to alleviate this issue to allow many mods to work together. What I mean is, most mods that use FORGE work together because that's what FORGE is for.